# Does Java 8 support interpolation

Tags: java, groovy, java-8

Groovy supports string interpolation operations. Here is an example

```
def name = "Tom"
println("Hello my name is ${name}")
```

Does Java 8 support string interpolation as the way Groovy does?

Any answer, greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java8 has nothing to do with this. For formatted console output, you can use `printf()` or the `format()` method of `System.out` Try this out.

```
System.out.printf("My name is: %s%n", "Tom");
```

Comment: So basically, no

Comment: @sh4d0w Should be the accepted answer really lol

Answer (score 0):

For formatted console output use of String.format is recommanded.  `System.out.println(String.format("My name is: %s%n", "Tom"));`

When logging a message there are several important requirements which must be fulfilled:

- The user must be able to easily retrieve the logs  The format of all
  the logged message must be uniform to allow the user to easily read the log.
- Logged data must actually be recorded.
- Sensitive data must only be logged securely.
- If a program directly writes to the standard outputs, there is absolutely no way to comply with those requirements.

That's why defining and using a dedicated logger is highly recommended. org.slf4j.Logger is one of the standard Logger factory and is easy to use.

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(<ClassName>.class);
LOGGER.info("My name is: {}", "Tom");
```